# Conditional linking to an CSS file

Tags: jsf-2

In my JSF2 project I want to include following two style sheet to my Facelet page based on a condition which is to be obtained from a managed bean.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu_style_1.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu_style_2.css" type="text/css" />
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<h:outputStylesheet  name="css/menu_style_1.css" target="head" rendered="#{myBean.myValue eq 'myCondition1'}"/>
```

and

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/menu_style_2.css" target="head" rendered="#{myBean.myValue eq 'myCondition2'}"/>
```

OR... you can do it in one line...

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/#{myBean.myValue == 'true' ? 'menu_style_1.css' : 'menu_style_2.css'}" target="head" />
```

I guess if you want to stick to the link  tag you can try something like that

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/#{myBean.myValue == 'true' ? 'menu_style_1.css' : 'menu_style_2.css'}" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Please note that the `library` attribute isn't used correctly here. A third alternative is to just let the bean return `1` or `2` so that you can use `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/menu_style_#{bean.cssId}.css" />` without any conditionals.